# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase') with select2 and Pugx

Tags: symfony, jquery-select2

For an autocomplete with symfony, I use the bundle [PUGX](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle/blob/master/docs/index.md) but using select2 version 3.5.2-browserify throw me an error :

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')

My JS file :

```php
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2/select2';
import '@pugx/autocompleter-bundle/js/autocompleter-select2';

$('#postal_code_search_zipcode').autocompleter({
    url_list: '/postalCode_search',
    url_get: '/postalCode_get/',
    // min_length: 3,
    otherOptions: {
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        formatNoMatches: 'Pas trouvé',
        formatSearching: 'Je cherche',
        formatInputTooShort: 'Insérer au minimum les 3 premiers chiffre'
    }
})
```

My Controller :

```php
{
    #[Route('/postalCode_search', name: "postalCode_search", defaults:["_format" => "json"])]
    public function searchPostalCode(Request $request, CityRepository $cityRepository): Response
    {
        $query = $request->query->get('q');
        $results = $cityRepository->findLikePostalCode($query);

        return $this->render('json/postal_code.json.twig', ['postalCodes' => $results]);
    }

    #[Route('/postalCode_get', name: "postalCode_get")]
    public function getPostalCode(string $id, CityRepository $cityRepository): Response
    {
        $postalCode = $cityRepository->find($id);

        if (null !== $postalCode){
            $result = $postalCode->getZipcode().' '.$postalCode->getName();
        }else{
            $result = 'Aucun résultat';
        }

        return $this->json($result);
    }
}
```

My json twig:

```
[{% for postalCode in postalCodes -%}
    {{ {id: postalCode.id, label: postalCode.zipcode ~ ' ' ~ postalCode.name, value: postalCode.zipcode ~ ' ' ~ postalCode.name}|json_encode|raw }}
    {%- if not loop.last %},
    {% endif -%}
 {%- endfor %}
]
```

If I use jquery-ui instead, when typing, it show me all I need but not with select2, any idea?

Comment: can you try require('select2') instead of import 'select2/select2';

Comment: I try 'require ('select2/select2');' but same result